# Nodejs - Passport authenticate always return failure redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, passport.js, passport-local

I'm making a form login by passportJs and it always return failureRedirect. I have search in stack overflow for this issue, but still not have the correct answer. Here is my code:

- Form making form jade:

  ```
  form(method='post', action='/users/login', enctype='multipart/form-data')
   .form-group
     label Username
     input.form-control(name='username', type='text'     placeholder='Enter Username')
  .form-group
    label Password
    input.form-control(name='password', type='password' placeholder='Enter password')
  input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', value='Login')
  ```

Router Hanlde is using express framework form Nodejs and passport middleware:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
 done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
});
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
},
function(username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
            console.log('Unknown User');
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Unknown User'
            });
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                console.log('Invalid Password');
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Invalid Password'
                });
            }
         });
      });
   }
));

  router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'
}), function(req, res) {
console.log('Authentication Successful');
req.flash('success', 'You are logged in ');
res.redirect('/');
 });
```

Comment: Can you share codes for `getUserByUsername` and `comparePassword` functions?

Comment: @user2235057 Yes: I write it in models folder, file user.js:


            module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
 var query = {username: username};
 User.findOne(query, callback);
   }


     module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
   var query = {username: username};
   User.findOne(query, callback);
      }

Comment: Is this the complete code for `getUserByUsername` function? If that is the case, there is issue in that function. The codes should have been something like: module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){ var query = {username: username}; User.findOne(query, function(err, user){callback(err, user)}); }  and you have not shared `comparePassword` function so I am not sure if that is right as well.

Comment: @user2235057 
thanks you for you response. I missing to share the function [comparePassoword]. Here it is:
         module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
 bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
  if(err) return callback(err);
  callback(null, isMatch);
 });
}

Comment: @user2235057: Thanks you very much. I have pass the function. It so awesome. You must be a master of passport middleware and express framework.

If you can, please answer in this question. For another have the same issue like me can find the answer. If any more source code, please tell me, i will provide the source code. Thank a lot for you support.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. I am just an average javascript developer :). I have posted solution as answer, it would be great if you could accept it.

Comment: Thank you for upvote but accepting answer will help others understand that it worked in your case. You can accept answer by clicking on tick mark beside your answer. And accepting the answer would add 2 points to your reputation too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `getUserByUsername` function you shared in comments, it looks like you are not making call to callback function of `getUserByUsername` in correct way and therefore it is not getting `user` object resulting into failure redirect. The function you shared was:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username}; 
  User.findOne(query, callback); 
}
```

Changing it to following should fix your issue:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username}; 
  User.findOne(query, function(err, user) {
    callback(err, user);
  }); 
}
```